# How to create salted hash with output length under 40 characters

Tags: node.js, passwords, bcrypt

Is there a way to make BcryptJS (or a similarly secure hashing library available through NPM) output hashes with a length under 40 characters?

My intention is to use Bcrypt to hash a user ID so that it can be used as a password for a third party service that only accepts email+password logins. However, the service only accepts passwords with length of 40 characters or less.

How could I accommodate this restriction while still keeping passwords secure.

FYI, the user ID and output password will be visible to the user.